# after running Restlet for android I get memory leak

Tags: java, android, restlet, freeze

I run different Post, Delete, Put and Get, with no particular order and after running in debuger mode for a while a error starts to happen:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity... Connector Error (1002) - The connector encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request

Caused by: Internal Connector Error (1002) - The connector encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.doError(ClientResource.java:599)

Or a memory leak is encountered with GC_Concurring running indefinitely.

my code is:

```
    int id = 12662;
    Integer[] devicesInt = new Integer[2];
              devicesInt[0] = 1;
              devicesInt[1] = 2;
    Area area2 = new Area(id,"New 2 Sample Image",devicesInt, "3_New_Sample Name");


    area2.postArea();

    area2.name = "modify name again";

    Result resPut2 = area.putArea();

           //other PUT,POST, DELETE, GET METHODS DOWN HERE
```

In the Area class I have:

```
    //update an area with PUT.
public Result putArea(){

    // Initialize the resource proxy.
    ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(getLocalUrl() + "/" + this.id);      
    cr.setRequestEntityBuffering(true);
    AreaResource areaRes = cr.wrap(AreaResource.class);
    return areaRes.store(this);         
}


//DELETE an area.
public void postArea(){

    // Initialize the resource proxy.
    ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(getLocalUrl());      
    cr.setRequestEntityBuffering(true);
    AreaResource areaRes = cr.wrap(AreaResource.class);
    //return areaRes.storeWithPost(this);           
}
```

Comment: Which version of Restlet are you using? V2.2 or below?

Comment: Iam using restlet 2.21.

Comment: Do you rely on the NIO extension (org.restlet.ext.nio) or just on the internal connector in org.restlet.jar?

Comment: just on the internal connector org.restlet.jar.

Comment: I had a lot of problems with restlet. Finaly solved them. It might be more than one thing. One of the issues (GC_Concurring running indefinitely), appeared to be because the code was inside the models class (i.e. Area). It also seamed as if the debuger was memorizing the errors, ie I run the code, and it worked fine. But if I entered a wrong url or something, and later fixed it, errors kept comming, despite being the same code and doing clean, as if it had memorized the error.